# SQL where statement thousands of values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a spreadsheet with 12290 unique reference numbers on that I need to find any payment transactions against.

For a handful id just manually do this. But for a large number like this what would be the best way?

Can I reference a notepad file in a query in anyway?

Thanks,

Comment: I do this all the time, and I find the simplest way is to push the data into a temporary table, then join to this in SSMS. For example, using EXCEL or Google Sheets, my formula might look like `=CONCATENATE("INSERT INTO #temp SELECT '", A2, "';")`. I then copy this formula down all of the rows, and cut and paste it into a new query window... adding a `CREATE TABLE #temp (something VARCHAR(50));` above the `INSERT` statements.

Comment: Take a look here to see how to link on your query the data on a notepad file in CSV format : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dfa4ee37-4c3d-414d-baa2-f7869aae9a49/linked-server-to-comma-delimted-text-files?forum=transactsql

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit long for a comment.

Although you *could* put the values into a giant `in` statement, I would recommend that you load the data into a separate table.  That table can have the reference number as a primary key.  You can then use a query (`join` or `exists`) to get matching values.

This also has the nice side effect that you have the reference numbers in the database, so they can be used for another purpose -- or archived so you can keep track of what your application is doing.

Answer (score 1):

While using @Gordon Linoff's answer.

To upload data there are various methods.

1. As in the main comments ie. writing a formula in XL and copying that and run the script in Management Studio (I would keep that in a permanent table to avoid doing the same in the future, if the list is not going to be changed often.) and also I wouldn't recommend this for 12000 records, but for less than 100 records it is OK.

   [image]
2. Using Import Export wizard of Management Studio
   [image]
3. Create a table to hold that data and open that in Management Studio, in Edit mode and copy-paste data to the table.